# Selenium-WebDriver Sleep() ignored and switchTo() changes the context

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm a beginner using Selenium WebDriver, I want to run a couple of test consisting of clicking a button, filling a textarea and then comparing some text, currently I'm facing a couple of problems, here's my code:

```
    var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;
    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    driver.get('somepage');
    driver.findElement(By.id('button-id')).then(function(el) {
        console.log("Button found");
        driver.sleep(1000);
        el.click();
        // After click move to an iframe insde the page and do more stuff
        driver.switchTo().frame(0);
    });
```

Running this returns the error `element reference: element is not attached to the page document`which I've narrowed down to the frame switching changing the context where driver searches for the button element DESPITE executing AFTER finding said button, when commenting that line I get the message in console but then the button is inmediatly clicked, I've tried with implicit and explicit waits as well and they are completely ignored. Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "testing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "chat-questions.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "^76.0.0",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.4"
  }
}
```

Any idea why the sleep is ignored and the frame is changed before it should even execute?
How do I fix this and what is the cause? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing ***await***

Check some example to get familiar with syntax  [Test Example 1](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/test/builder_test.js) and [Test Example : element_finding_test.js](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/test/element_finding_test.js)

```
    var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;
    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    await driver.get('somepage');
    driver.findElement(By.id('button-id')).then(function(el) {
        console.log("Button found");
        await  driver.sleep(1000);
        await  el.click();
        // After click move to an iframe insde the page and do more stuff
        await driver.switchTo().frame(0);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I get the error: await is only valid in async function

Comment: You will need to put this code in async function const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

async function main() {
    let driver = await new Builder()
        .forBrowser('firefox')
        .build();

  await driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr')
  
  const element = await driver.findElement(By.name('q'))
  
  await element.sendKeys('webdriver', Key.RETURN)
  await driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000)
  await driver.quit()
}
main()